# What is the best setting on iPad for reading eBooks

Tags: substitute-tool, technology, comfort, eyesight

I am an avid reader of eBooks and I do that mostly on an iPad. But there are many people who warn of deterioration of eyesight due to continuous exposure to the screen of an iPad. But I can't give up this habit. So what are the best settings I can use on an iPad to ensure my eye sight is saved in the long run, somehow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic. Asking which settings to use on a piece of software doesn't fit within the scope of Lifehacks. Here is a [related meta](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/2403/168) on this type of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any backlit screen isn't optimal for reading; an e-ink screen such as that on the Amazon Kindle is preferred. But to answer your question...

As to avoid [computer vision syndrome](http://www.webmd.com/eye-health/computer-vision-syndrome), the 20-20-20 rule is very effective. Quoting from [this article](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/eyestrain/basics/prevention/con-20032649):

> The 20-20-20 rule: Every 20 minutes, take your eyes off your computer and look at something 20 feet (6 metre) away for at least 20 seconds.

I like to use the 20<sup>4</sup> rule, which is the above, but ALSO using the recommended 20 inches (50 cm) between the monitor/tablet and your eyes.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try it out. But I can't keep an 9.7 inches iPad 20 inches away from me as I'm reading a book, not watching a movie.

Comment: @SandySands It doesn't have to be that far. The monitor I'm using right now it only 12" away.

Comment: Oh, alright then.

Comment: @Mooseman i will leave this here. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22762257
You don't back your answer with any proof (the first part).